# Unable to perform sudo apt -get , how to solve?

Tags: software-installation, updates

```
sudo apt -get update
E: Command line option 'g' [from -get] is not understood in combination with the other options.

sudo apt -get
E: Command line option 'g' [from -get] is not understood in combination with the other options.
```

Comment: `apt-get`, not `apt -get`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get paragraph for certain option of command right away?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/898819/how-to-get-paragraph-for-certain-option-of-command-right-away) Try my answer to the linked question using the command *apt* and the option *-get* (the same as in your question) and you will get the answer to your question right away.

Answer (score 4):

You have a space between "apt" and "-get"; "apt-get" is the command you are trying to use. So:

```
apt-get update
apt-get upgrade
apt-get install apache2
apt-get remove apache2
```

etc etc..

Alternatively, you can use "apt" to manage packages. I use it in 16.04 and it has a few extras which make it my go to package manager over apt-get:

```
apt update
apt upgrade
apt install apache2
apt remove apache2
```

etc etc.